# Connection to Site folder via SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, webdav

Ok this one is hard for me to get my head around but let me explain what is happening. I have a sharepoint (maybe irrelevant) site that uses https. I wrote a c# program to download files from a folder from that site. My path to that folder is

```
string pathA = @"\\mysite.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\abc\Lists\Images\Screen Slides\";
```

So the issue is when you boot your machine, the code will throw the error: Folder not found. My workaround to getting the C# program to open the folder takes two steps that I do not know how to code. I will open that URL into a run command it will say it cannot connect the first try. Then I run it again it will connect. So it takes two run commands to connect to the folder. After this the C# program will have not issues finding and accessing the folder.

My guess is that I need to use some sort of credentials for my C# code to connect to the folder without doing the work around. I am looking for a way to connect to the site with code so the users do not have to change any settings on their machine. Thanks

**EDIT:** Here is the code that will compare the SSL folder with local directoy. From there it will download or delete files

```
string pathA = @"\\mysite.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\abc\Lists\Images\Screen Slides\";
string pathB = imagepath;

System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathA);
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathB);

// Take a snapshot of the file system.
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

//A custom file comparer defined below
FileCompare myFileCompare = new FileCompare();

// Find the set difference between the two folders. 
// Check if there is new images in network drive and if not download to C. 
var queryList1Only = (from file in list1
      select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare);

Console.WriteLine("The following files are in list1 but not list2:");
foreach (var v in queryList1Only)
{
    File.Copy(v.FullName, Path.Combine(pathB, v.Name));
    Console.WriteLine("Download done");
    Console.WriteLine(v.FullName);
}

// Find the set difference between the two folders. 
// Check if there is old images in C drive and if so delete them. 
var queryList2Only = (from file in list2
      select file).Except(list1, myFileCompare);

Console.WriteLine("The following files are in C:/ but not \\share:");
foreach (var v in queryList2Only)
{  
    File.Delete(v.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine("Delete done");
    Console.WriteLine(v.FullName);
}

// Keep the console window open in debug mode.
Console.WriteLine("File Sync Done");
```

Comment: Please share the code you're using that actually uses the `pathA` variable.

Comment: I second EricLaw: what are you doing exactly to download those files?

Comment: The issue is not downloading, it is connecting to the folder. I will edit post to add code

Comment: Just found out if I use @"\\mysite.com\sites\abc\Lists\Images\Screen Slides\"; I have the same issue